# Meaning of "starch to pull it off"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I was reading [my book](https://books.google.com/books?id=7M-V0cqNMHAC&lpg=PA263&ots=_BRuaWqkNd&pg=PA262#v=onepage&q&f=false) came across with below sentence.

> I don't believe a word of that story because it would take a guy with a **great deal of starch to pull it off**.

I think it means that, given the meaning of *starch* and *pull off*, the story is weird and requires huge amounts of time and concentration to be figured out.

Am I correct? If no, would you kindly explain the meaning to me.

Comment: Where did you look the word up? See [Definition 4b](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/starch).

Comment: @J.R. Macmilan, by the way, why negative pont?

Comment: If "it" from the phrase relates to something that the guy from the story did, then you're missing the correct meaning. Are you talking about a piece of literary work or about the actions of the character. Clear that up, please.

Comment: @J.R. Rompey: I was doubted that between "it needs great amounts of energy" or "it needs great amount of imaginations, examinations and these sorts of things "

Comment: If you looked up a word, you should tell us where you looked it up, and also tell us what you found there. (That's Point #3 on our [Details, please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) meta post.) You should also tell us the name of this book, so people can find more context if need be. Ideally, this information should be edited into your question, not merely included in subsequent comments.

Comment: It's really hard to get Google Books to go to a specific page. The relevant passage is in the first search result for "Wordsearch 16".

Comment: @Martha At the top of the page when you're reading a book on Google Books, there is a link button (it looks like a chain) - you can navigate to the page you want, and then click that button to get a link to that particular page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Starch](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/starch) in a figurative sense means:

> - (Informal) vigor; energy; stamina; boldness.

To [pull it off](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pull-it-off?&o=100074&s=t):

> - (Slang) - To accomplish something; succeed; make it: *pull it off and keep the patients coming back for more (1887+)*

(Dictionary.com)

- It would take a greal deal of courage/boldness to make it.

Comment: Think of what starch does to fabric: It causes it to stiffen.  So in a figurative sense, a person with a lot of starch would have a stiff spine, e.g. be tough and rigid.  That's the likely implication.  It's probably a bit antiquated now, but that's the impression that I get.

Comment: There are lots of informal ways to say "courage" or "boldness", like *guts* or *balls*. I believe *starch* was chosen here specifically for the pun: the story involves a thief carrying off the loot in plain sight because it's in a laundry bag and he has the presence of mind to say "I'll have the shirts back on Friday".

Answer (score 3):

If "it" from the phrase relates to something that the guy from the story did, then you're missing the correct meaning. What you are talking about - a piece of literary work or the actions of the character, that needed a lot of courage - can only be guessed by the words "that story".

So, the meaning of the sentence may be this: It's hardly believable that a regular guy could manage to do what the character from the story did, and that's why the reader didn't believe a word of that story.

In other words, the character of the story did something which the reader thinks unbelievable to be done by an ordinary man, and he, the reader, didn't believe it

Comment: The highlighted sentence is the response of a guy listening to another guy narrating a story about a robbery. see here: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=QtJoCwAAQBAJ&pg=RA3-PR99&dq=1100+words+you+must+know+week+16&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSufXqhqDMAhViOMAKHSyNDWwQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=1100%20words%20you%20must%20know%20week%2016&f=false

Comment: after you opened the above link, find section "wordsearch 16". there are some pages you must turn to reach to "wordsearch 16"

Comment: Thanks for the link. Seems a pretty useful book to better one's command of the second language.